# Is Ganache GUI real EVM?

Tags: truffle, evm, ganache

I was wondering whether Ganache GUI is real EVM or just a replica of it. Because its throughput and latency are way better than Geth client. Any comments on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering whether Ganache GUI is real EVM or just a replica of it.

It's an implementation of the EVM. Whether this makes it a "replica" is more of a philosophical discussion. Without actually checking the code, I'd assume it's a faithful implementation of the specification in the Yellow Paper.

> Because its throughput and latency are way better than Geth client.

Ganache is a test environment, so it perhaps isn't fair to compare it to clients operating on the public mainnet.

Ganache will immediately mine a new block - or at least simulate the mining of a new block - for every new transaction, making the block time negligible. This artificially low block time allows for quicker testing. This is orthogonal to the question of whether the Ganache simulates the EVM correctly.

If you want Ganache to more faithfully mirror the mainnet's PoW block time, you can use Ganache's `--blockTime` option.